# To transfer images in a Smartphone to a computer using Python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a Facial recognition project which requires me to access images clicked by my phone on a computer. Is there a way in Python to automatically transfer images clicked by my phone to my computer through some servers or any other means, so that the python scripts running on my computer can fetch those images and process it?

Comment: Yes, you need to send the image (or link to the image) from your phone to your computer and write a Python program to receive or retrieve that image. One of the methods would to use a websocket

Answer (score 2):

Interesting project. I've not done this myself but it really depends on what you mean by "transfer images clicked" and the scope of how often and how many people will be sending photos from smartphone to backend python process.

- If you have pictures already on your phone you can probably just go
  to your Android/iPhone picture gallery and save or share them then
  download to your system which does not involve Python. It's manual
  but really easy for a one time dump.
- If you want to automate the above steps and have them downloaded automatically you probably need to look into a
  RESTful API for example [google photo
  api](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/overview)
  then use a [request library](https://github.com/requests/requests) or something similar to pull them. Still
  manual in terms of pushing your photos into one album but at least
  you do not need to host anything and it's one click to download.
- If you want to have others take photos and you host a back end that
  may involve a web framework like flask or django and the
  [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)
  method googling "getUserMedia" and `<insert framework>` can probably get you some pretty good starting points.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of achieving this. They vary in the use and process that you are having. I will focus on a basic one, that has the virtue of persistence, thus, allowing you to resend and debug in cases of failure.

As this solution requires a big scope of integration I will outline the flow from which you can derive the different blocks needed to implement.

Basically, you transfer (upon taking them, once a day etc.) the pictures to a database that can be accessed from any device anywhere with your chosen API (given the DB etc.). Then, your scripts can fetch the "delta" of pictures that weren't processed yet.